# What is Groot's body made of?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, groot

There have been questions such as "what species is Groot" but what I'm wondering is what exactly he *is.*  He appears obviously to be simply wood, but he is an alien creature not from Earth and never catches fire or anything.  Plus, in *Avengers: Infinity War* Baby Groot

> cuts off his arm to hold Thor's new ax.  This doesn't burn through and is surprisingly durable, despite Groot seemingly being just wood.

And in *Guardians of the Galaxy*,

> Groot wrapping himself around everyone helps them survive an explosion, something normal wood would likely be unable to do.

Does this have anything to do with his species?  Is he just alien wood?

Comment: Does he weigh the same as a duck?

Comment: I asked him (via twitter); https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TjND.png

Comment: I am not certain, but there is a fan theory that he is made from 'the tree of the world', mentioned in TFA.

Comment: "Some say it's a flower. Some say it's a weed. I never gave it much thought." - Jim Stafford

Comment: According to Groot, "I am Groot."

Comment: That wasn’t baby Groot, that was awkward-teenage-years Groot.

Comment: @KnoxBoyd - Drawing a blank on what TFA means in this context - all I can think of is *The Force Awakens*, which can't be right....

Comment: Wait, there are people who stayed wake through _Infinity War_?

Comment: @RDFozz I believe it would be CA:TFA (i.e. Captain America: The First Avenger)... but yeah referring to it only as TFA is confusing!

Comment: "The tree of the world" sounds like Yggdrasil to me - I'd expect to hear about that in one of the Thor movies, as it's part of Norse mythology.

Comment: @RDFozz  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In his first appearance back in *Tales to Astonish* 13 (1960), he was a verbose alien conqueror who was immune to our puny Earth weapons . . . until a scientist infected him with termites. So a bazooka didn't scratch him but a bug could be fatal.

I think this set the stage for his invulnerability being inconsistent. His second appearance was against the Hulk and he seemed to have Hulk-like invincibility but later appearances made him seem like cheap cardboard.

Officially, he might be alien wood but his powers vary from writer to writer.

Comment: Hardly the first alien menace to be felled by a bug....

Answer (score -1):

It isn't confirmed by anyone, YET.

But I do think that there is a magical element at play here.

Once the axe was completely manufactured, a couple of things happened:

1. Thor was seemingly healed of burns inflicted by the star.
2. He was able to summon the ax to his hand and it seems the ax itself was enchanted with greater strength and power than even Uru should have granted it.

Many of the powerful Asgardian weapons used inscribed runes of power to imbue them with magical aspects, durability, lightweight and more. Heimdall's blade is likely a prime example of this, it's magic making it the key for the Bifrost.

While Groot's arm is no mere wood it does appear that these runic enchantments empower the weapon as a whole once assembled.

Comment: “it seems the ax itself was enchanted with greater strength and power than even Uru should have granted it” — does it? How?